# How to download a encrypted m3u8 in iOS. Even if would able to download I could not able to play the encrypted video in offline mode

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming, m3u8, avasset, fairplay

*In earlier case of my I have played non encrypted .m3u8 video in offline mode*

1. I have download a *.m3u8 extension video file* which is not encrypted 
   and I have played that video.
2. This video is download in the formate of *.movpkg extension* format.
3. I have download this video using *AVAsset download Session*

*But in the case of encrypted video*

1. I can download the .m3u8 extension video and this video get saved in extension of .movpkg
2. The issue rise when the saved video is played without any internet connection I know this reason for this because the *decryption key is not available* for it. So that video can decrypt and play in player level it self
3. Is there any possibility to play the saved video file without using internet(offline)
4. Do I need to use the apple fair play concept to play m3u8 video?
   if so how can implement it in server side?
5. Have anyone used apple fair play concept?
6. How can implement the fair play concept in the FFmpeg Convertor?
7. Is there any method to *override the key delivery mode in AVPlayer*?

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Currently, I am facing the same problems.

Comment: No I have solved the problem but have raised a ticket in AWS but in AZURE you can use the fair play Streaming to over come this issue

Comment: can you please explain in details? I can't understand what you are talking about?

Comment: You need used Azure cloud storage and their you need to set the Content protection type to DRM and Select the Fair play. after that you can flow the normal AVAssertURLDownloadSession

Comment: it takes charge to use. I want the ios default process as it can freely excess. So, do you know how to do it?

Comment: You can download a HLS with is encrypted but you cannot play in offline mode

Comment: @maoj Kumar,  I have to show reasons why it is impossible to play in offline mode to my client. So do you have any source that will help me convince them?

Comment: Ask your client to buy you a DRM so that the content will play in offline mode or Don't using any encryption to the video content

Comment: The last time I checked it, the Apple Developer website have WWDC talks and sample code for offline playback of FairPlay media. They look pretty solid. I am planning to try them out. Here is the link: [FairPlay Streaming - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/fps/)

Comment: I have already tried it and could not able to find the solution